# Streamplot in one direction

Tags: plotting, graphics

R gives explicitly the seeding points and I want the stream lines to be drawn in one direction only, outside the circle

```
R=Table[{ Cos[i], Sin[i]},{i,0,2 Pi,0.2}];
L=ListPlot[R,PlotStyle->PointSize[Large]];
SS=StreamPlot[{x,x+y},{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2},StreamPoints->{R , 1 ,2}      
  ,StreamScale->{21 ,12,.001   },ImageSize->Large,Axes->True,Epilog->Point[R] ]
```

[image]

Comment: Use `RegionFunction -> (#1^2 + #2^2 >= 1 &)`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what if the seeding points are given explicitly by hand?

Answer (score 2):

```
r = Table[{Cos[i], Sin[i]}, {i, 0, 2 Pi, 0.2}];
StreamPlot[{x, x + y}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 StreamPoints -> {r, 1, 2}, StreamScale -> {21, 12, .001}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, RegionFunction -> (#1^2 + #2^2 > 1 &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]